# VB.NET - recursive function runs again after exiting function

Tags: vb.net, recursion

I have a function that returns a date N days ahead from given date. If the returned date falls on weekend or holiday, it should be moved to the next business day.

```
Function NDaysAhead(ByVal dtStartDate As DateTime, ByVal nDays As Integer, ByVal isSatWorkDay As Boolean) As DateTime
    Dim dt As DateTime
    dt = dtStartDate.AddDays(nDays)
    If (Weekday(dt) = 7) And Not isSatWorkDay Then
        dt = dt.AddDays(2)
    ElseIf (Weekday(dt) = 1) Then
        dt = dt.AddDays(1)
    End If
    If IsHoliday(dt) Then
        NDaysAhead(dt, 1, isSatWorkDay)
    End If
    Return dt
    Exit Function
End Function
```

For some reason, after it returns the date and reaches `End Function`, it goes back to `NDaysAhead(dt, 1, isSatWorkDay)` with the previous value of `dt` (without even checking `If IsHoliday(dt)` condition).

I am pretty sure that there're other ways to get what I need, but I would really want to understand why is it acting this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the `dt` variable when calling the recursive method:

```
NDaysAhead(dt, 1, isSatWorkDay)
```

should be

```
dt = NDaysAhead(dt, 1, isSatWorkDay)
```

But I think you should simplify your code like this, because there is really no need for the recursion:

```
Function NDaysAhead(ByVal dtStartDate As DateTime, ByVal nDays As Integer, ByVal isSatWorkDay As Boolean) As DateTime
    Dim dt As DateTime
    dt = dtStartDate.AddDays(nDays)
    Do Until (Not dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday) AndAlso 
             (Not dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday) AndAlso 
             (Not IsHoliday(dt))
        dt = dt.AddDays(1)
    Loop
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Wow such an obvious error... Thanks a lot! And Loop solution does look better.

Comment: But I still don't understand why it goes back after it reaches `End Function`

Comment: I think what you are seeing is that you have entered a recursion of the function, then when it hits `Return`, you then step back to the first call of the function, which was is the line `NDaysAhead(dt, 1, isSatWorkDay)`